# Magento 2.1 Points System for selling products

Tags: extensions, products, products-management, magento-2.1.3

In my project, the products values are set by `Points` instead of real currencies and the store customers would have kind of a "`points wallet`", that they would be able to trade for products.They would be purchasing products with points instead of real currency.

Does Magento have some kind of `built-in feature or extensions (free or paid)` that allows the configuration of such functionality?

**Note: - This is not like reward point system such as earning some points by buying some products.**

My Requirement:

I will brief you about my exact scenario. I have two different stores on one website. Both have different domains. Like shopping.com and members.com Ok. Users who are already a member can only login in members.com site. shopping.com is open to all type of users. Users can switch between these stores.

***Now my issue comes here:*** When a member user buys some items from shoppings.com he/she will get some points like you said credit amount. And this points will be added to their account wallet. For this requirement, I can use the extensions like Vivek mentioned in his answer.

But in members.com, the same user can buy items using this points from wallet not using actual currency payment. This is the part where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension like those who support credit amounts.
I am not sure whether there are some extension build for M-2
but I am sharing some example urls
http://www.magestore.com/magento-store-credit-extension.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-credits.html

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with my exact scenario. Can you please go through that and provide your opinions on that ? Thanks.